# How to set background image of a button to a base64 encoded image in ie 9+?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-9, data-uri

I have a button in my webpage which I want to set its background image to a base64 encoded data URI like this:

```html
<button type="button" disabled="true" style="width: 350px; height: 220px; background-image: url(&quot;data:image/png;base64, Qa=...;);"></button>
```

The button above works in chrome, Firefox, and IE11 but not in IE9. The button is showing but the background image isn't shown. So How do I make it work in IE9?

Please note that all google results showed how to support IE8+ or svgs and what I want is to supported in IE9 with base64 data URI.

Comment: @mplungjan I don't need to support ie7 and under,only ie9 and above

Comment: @mplungjan and IE 11 works

Comment: Likely same method could be used - and IE10 does not I assume

Answer (score 1):

According to https://caniuse.com/#feat=datauri, data URIs can be used in IE8 and up, but there is a note that for IE8, the max URI length is 32KB. This should work in IE9 just like it does in IE11, but don't use `&quot;` and make sure there is no space after the first comma or anywhere else in the value:

```html
<button type="button" disabled="true" style="width: 350px; height: 220px; background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAQAAAADCAIAAAA7ljmRAAAAGElEQVQIW2P4DwcMDAxAfBvMAhEQMYgcACEHG8ELxtbPAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC);"></button>
```